# Why is my splice method not working for my to do list app?

Tags: javascript

I've read about the splice method for my todo list app but I don't know why this doesn't work.
https://codepen.io/dev999/pen/XRzMwx Could anyone please tell me how to fix my splice method so that it deletes the right to do item? Thank you! So far it seems to only delete the first item no matter what

```
function dele (position, amount) {
      var amount = 1; 
    var position = 
    ((parseInt(prompt("What is the number of the item you want to     delete?")))+1);
    var position = todo[position];


    todo.splice(position, amount);
  }
```

Comment: It looks like you probably don't want this line `var position = todo[position];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to change too much stuff to confuse you.

1st I added a `My todo list` to your HTML to show current to-do list.

2nd I'm calling `dispTodo();` each time you `add` or `dele` to update the current to-do list.

3rd array index started as 0,1,2,3 as position 1,2,3,4 so the input you need to do -1 not +1 (ex: 1st item has index of 0)

4th `todo.splice(position, 1);` will just remove the item from array.

```js
var todo = [];
// creating empty todo array

// todo function to add a to do one by one
function addTodo() {
  todo.push(prompt("Enter one item you want to add to your todo!"));
  dispTodo();
}

function dispTodo() {
  document.getElementById("todolist").innerHTML = todo;
}

function dele(position, amount) {
  var position =
    parseInt(prompt("What is the number of the item you want to delete?")) - 1;
  todo.splice(position, 1);
  dispTodo();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addTodo()"> Click here to add one to do of your choice to your list</button>
<button onclick="dele()"> Click here to delete a to do of your choice</button>
<button onclick="dispTodo()"> Click here to display your list of todos</button>

<div>My todo list:
  <div id="todolist"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @CodeLearner Welcome to stackOverflow, If any answer helps you [vote it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow), If the answer is what you looking for mark it as [Correct answe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the information and the warm welcome and I really appreciate your taking the time to walk me through this in plain English. I've only been learning JS for a month!

Answer (score 0):

This function doesn't need any arguments, assuming that `todo` is in the global scope.

```
function delete() {
  var choice = prompt("What is the number of the item you want to delete?")

  // need to call parseInt with 10 to ensure base10
  var pos = parseInt(choice, 10) + 1

  // remove 1 item, starting at `pos`
  todo.splice(pos, 1)     
}
```

Here's some recommended reading

1. [mdn document on Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?v=control)
2. [mdn document on parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 0):

You have unnecessarily overrided position variable.
And also if you want to remove proper list item you have to change this line

```
parseInt(prompt("What is the number of the item you want to     delete?"))+1
```

to

```
parseInt(prompt("What is the number of the item you want to     delete?"))-1
```